# What device will allow me to wire home with Ethernet, but no Wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

As more evidence emerges that Wifi is potentially harmful, I'm interested in wiring my home with ethernet and not using WiFi at home at all.

I'm currently just using a typical (cable-based) Comcast WiFi Router.  Is it possible to disable the broadcast (WiFi), while continuing internet through the ethernet cabling?

Comment: There's NO evidence WiFi is harmful. The evidence (and prior plausibility) is the opposite. Everything else is pseudo-science, FUD and gullible people.

Comment: There's actually quite a lot of evidence going back over 50 years.  Google the International Electromagnetic Field Alliance, a group of scientists trying to warn about the dangers now that EMF is ubiquitous.

Comment: I won't be wasting my time with crackpots. Double-blinded studies have definitely proved "EMF sensitivity" is just nocebo effect.

Comment: Danger from Wifi (if any) is so low its not funny.  If you are worried about this, then stop using computers, mobile phones, toaster, microwaves, induction cooktops, electrical wiring in the house, etc etc etc.  All of these are would be way worse for you.  And it is true that link to EMF for damage is not been proven.  However, static electricity is another matter altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can usually disable the Wi-Fi in any wireless router, and then just use its LAN Ethernet ports. You can connect additional Ethernet switches if you need more ports.

And yes, you could get other equipment as well. Any DOCSIS cable modem will be compatible with Comcast, and you can get modem-only cable modems. You can also get wired-only routers from most of the well known home networking brands. The Ubiquiti EdgeRouter line is very popular with serious home networkers.